# Query multiple models in Graphene Django

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-django, graphql-python

I have multiple models in Django named `model1`, `model2`, `model3`.
Each model has the same fields and the field `id` is the primary key.
I want to query this database using GraphQL. The query structure should be like below.

```
query{
      pod(model: "model1",id: "1")
        {
           id
           data1
           data2
        }
     }
```

This should get me the object for id 1 from model 1.
How can I do this in Django using Graphene ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map for your models and how you want it to be accessed from your graphql query. Do it like so:

```
def resolve_pod(self, root, info, model, id):
    model_map = {'model1': Model1, 'model2': Model2, 'model3': Model3}
    if model in model_map.keys():
        return model_map[model].objects.get(id=1)
    return None
```

Comment: How should I design the type class for this ?

Comment: It depends, are the fields for this models all the same? If they have specialized fields, you can create a `UnionType`.

Comment: I have completed this thing. The thing was to use UnionType in GraphQL. Thanks @JechChua